# I'm getting an invalid uri error when migrating a Magento 1.6.1 install to new Dedicated Server

Tags: magento

I'm getting the following error when migrating a Magento install to a new Dedicated server

I pretty experienced at cloning and migrating Magento but I can't figure out whats wrong here.

I have checked the new server for compatibility and thats fine..

This error is normally thrown when there is an underscore in the uri . i have tried different subdomains but keep getting the error. I have just migrated the same site to my dev server and it works fine - any ideas ?

```
Trace:
/home/shushush/public_html/shoponline/magento/lib/Zend/Uri.php(143): Zend_Uri_Http->__construct('http', '//www.shushusho...')
1 /home/shushush/public_html/shoponline/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(712): Zend_Uri::factory('http://www.shus...')
2 /home/shushush/public_html/shoponline/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(313): Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
3 /home/shushush/public_html/shoponline/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->_checkBaseUrl(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
4 /home/shushush/public_html/shoponline/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
5 /home/shushush/public_html/shoponline/magento/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
6 /home/shushush/public_html/shoponline/magento/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
7 {main}
```

Comment: What's the exact error text you're getting?  You included a stack trace, but not the message of the error itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your call stack, it appears this is the method that triggers the error/exception you're seeing

```
Zend_Uri_Http->__construct
```

Jumping to the source of that file, I'm guessing (since you didn't include the error text) this is the exception you're seeing.

```
#File: lib/Zend/Uri/Http.php
protected function __construct($scheme, $schemeSpecific = '')
{
    //...
    if ($this->valid() === false) {
        #require_once 'Zend/Uri/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Uri_Exception('Invalid URI supplied');
    }
    //...
}
```

Taking a look at the definition of the `valid` method

```
public function valid()
{
    // Return true if and only if all parts of the URI have passed validation
    return $this->validateUsername()
       and $this->validatePassword()
       and $this->validateHost()
       and $this->validatePort()
       and $this->validatePath()
       and $this->validateQuery()
       and $this->validateFragment();
}
```

you can see 7 methods Zend/Magento calls to determine if the URI is valid or not. One of these is failing.  I'd recommend adding some temporary debugging code to determine which method is returning false

```
public function valid()
{
    var_dump($this->validateUsername());
    var_dump($this->validatePassword());
    var_dump($this->validateHost());
    var_dump($this->validatePort());
    var_dump($this->validatePath());
    var_dump($this->validateQuery());
    var_dump($this->validateFragment());

    // Return true if and only if all parts of the URI have passed validation
    return $this->validateUsername()
       and $this->validatePassword()
       and $this->validateHost()
       and $this->validatePort()
       and $this->validatePath()
       and $this->validateQuery()
       and $this->validateFragment();
}
```

Then, once you know that, you can look at the definition of the method that's returning false and determine which characters it's failing on.

Comment: many thanks for your help - the problem seems to have cured itself ..?

Answer (score 6):

The problem was due to '_' . It won't recognise the underscore.

Comment: More specific is that don not using website url have an underscore in this such as magento_test.local using magentotest.local and it will be ok